# Fluid infinity loop jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use a simple script for a infinity loop but its not fluid i have test many duration and the result is not good

```
  setInterval(function(){
     $("#list ul").animate({marginTop:-100},800,function(){
        $(this).css({marginTop:0}).find("li:last").after($(this).find("li:first"));
     })
  }, 800);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qorbn7j0/

What is solution for a fluid loop ? Thanks

Comment: In addition to the answers below, use `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setInterval`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the easing to `linear`

```
setInterval(function(){
    $("#list ul").animate({marginTop:-100},800,'linear',function(){
        $(this).css({marginTop:0}).find("li:last").after($(this).find("li:first"));
    })
}, 800);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [easing](https://jqueryui.com/easing/) to `linear`.

```
setInterval(function(){
$("#list ul").animate({marginTop:-100},800,'linear',function(){
    $(this).css({marginTop:0}).find("li:last").after($(this).find("li:first"));
})
}, 800);
```